# Looking for tips to help 18GB file upload and finish to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

I'm trying to use azcopy to push large 18GB files to Azure Blob Storage...I have it working for smaller files BUT the larger ones seem to be hit or miss.

This is my script that grabs a workstations memory, zips it and tries to upload it to Azure Blob Storage.

```
$path = "C:\Windows\Temp\"

# Set Azure Blob forensic storage
$AzureURI = "https://something.blob.core.windows.net/storagepath"
# Set Location 
Set-Location -Path C:\Windows\Temp\
$env:AZCOPY_CONCURRENCY_VALUE=4

# Download AzCopy
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v10-windows" -OutFile AzCopy.zip -UseBasicParsing
  
# Expand Archive
Expand-Archive ./AzCopy.zip ./AzCopy -Force

Get-ChildItem ./AzCopy/*/azcopy.exe | Move-Item -Destination "C:\Windows\Temp\azcopy.exe"

# Download Raptor Grab Memory from Azure Blob Storage 
$File = "Raptor_GrabMemory.exe"
$AzureToolURI = "https://something.blob.core.windows.net/forensiccollections/Raptor_GrabMemory.exe?sp=racwl&st=2023-02-27T21:18:50Z&se=2024-02-28T05:1(snip)"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $AzureToolURI -OutFile $File

# Grab the memory and zip it
.\Raptor_GrabMemory.exe

# Grab the memory file
$file = Get-Childitem –Path $path -Include CTAM_* -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# use azcopy to push file to blob storage 
.\azcopy.exe cp $file $AzureURI --check-length=false 2>&1
```

The only success I've had was to set AZCOPY_CONCURRENCY_VALUE to 4... but even that is still hit or miss. I'm not that concerned about speed, if this takes 8-10 hours it doesn't matter as long as it finishes.

Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: Worth a try, but have you tried lowering the thread count to 2 or 1; ex. `azcopy /NC:1`.  That's assuming the concurrent operations are overwhelming your connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to upload 18 GB files to Azure blob using the below PowerShell using `Azcopy copy`, and it got uploaded successfully.

```
$StorageAccountName = "kamalistore"
$ContainerName = "kamali"
$LocalPath = "C:\Windows\storageblob"
$SAS = "SASToken"
$URI = "https://$StorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/$ContainerName$SAS"
azcopy copy "$LocalPath" "$URI" --recursive
```

**Output:**
[image]

Once ran the above code files are uploaded successfully to **Azure blob**.
[image]

Alternatively, you can use the `As-Job` command to copy the files to Azure blob.  `As-Job` is used to check backend job status, while uploading Large files to Azure Blob.

```
$destinationPath = "C:\Windows\storageblob"

$fileName = Split-Path -Path $destinationPath -Leaf
    
$storageAccountConnectionString =
"BlobEndpoint=https://kamalistore.blob.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://kamalistore.queue.core.windows.net/;FileEndpoint=https://kamalistore.file.core.windows.net/;TableEndpoint=https://kamalistore.table.core.windows.net/;SASToken"
$containerName = "samplecontainer"
$storageAccountName ="kamalistore"
$resourceGroupName ="Kamali-RG"
$GetStorageAccountContext = Get-AzStorageAccount -Name $storageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
$storageContext = $GetStorageAccountContext.Context
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Context $storageContext -Container $containerName -AsJob
Get-Job
```

**Output:**
[image]

Once ran the above code files are uploaded successfully to **Azure blob**.
[image]

Comment: Whoa, wow, big time thank you!!! Thank you for the effort, snapshots and code!!